# Condition for a system of $n$ equation in $n$ unknowns to have a solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modules, systems-of-equations

Let $A$ be a ring and $U:=(a_{ij})_{i,j}$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over $A$.

> If $U$ is right invertible, for every sequence $(b_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$
> of elements of $A$, the system of equations
> $$\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j=b_i\,(1\leq i\leq n)$$ has a solution.

Let $f:A^{\oplus n}\rightarrow A^{\oplus n}$ be the $A$-linear mapping sending $x\in A^{\oplus n}$ to $\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j\right)_{1\leq i\leq n}$. Suppose $C:=(c_{jk})_{j,k}$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over $A$ such that $UC=I_n$. We want to show that this implies that $f$ is surjective.

Let $b\in A^{\oplus n}$. Note that $(\delta_{ik})_{i,k}=UC=\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}c_{jk}\right)_{i, k}$. Then for each $1\leq i \leq n$, we have $1=\delta_{ii}=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}c_{ji}$ and so
$$b_i=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}(c_{ji}b_i).$$
But this is useless because $(c_{ji}b_i)_{1\leq j\leq n}$ depends on $i$. What am I doing wrong? How can I show that $f$ is surjective?

Comment: Define $x:=Cb$ and calculate $Ux$.